# MongoDB nested aggregation based on time values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a structure like this coming from IOT sensor device

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8e1af3f1563046e084cf65"),
    "value" : 462.2382850719,
    "start" : 1586293200001,
    "year"  : 2020,
    "month" : "04",
    "day" : "07",
    "hour" : "21",
    "channelId" : 3462
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8e1af3f1563046e084cf64"),
    "value" : 1636.8770905333,
    "start" : 1586289600001,
     "year"  : 2020,
    "month" : "04",
    "day" : "07",
    "hour" : "19",
    "channelId" : 3462
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8e1af3f1563046e084cf63"),
    "value" : 1665.4116577475,
    "start" : 1586286000001,
    "year"  : 2020,
    "month" : "04",
    "day" : "07",
    "hour" : "20",
    "channelId" : 3462
}]
```

I want to group this structure first by channelId, then by year,month,day and hour. I want to develop this sort of nested structure

```
{"channel_id":XXX,"aggregates":[2020:[04:[01:[00:AVG_VALUE,01:AVG_VALUE...],...],...]}
```

Similar like this

```
   output = [
    {
        channelId: 3462,
        "value": '',
        aggregates: [
            {
                year: 2020, 
                months: [
                    {
                        month: 4,
                        value: '',
                        days: [
                            {
                                day: 7,
                                value: '',
                                hours: [
                                    { hour: 19, value: '' },
                                    { hour: 20, value: '' },
                                    { hour: 21, value: '' }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
    }
]
```

I can do one level $group by and then push the $$ROOT in it, but don't know how to go nested with groups. Do I have to use reduce logic or any.

Need help

Comment: You can group on multiple fields; in this case, "year", "month", etc.

Comment: How to group them nested?

Comment: `{ $group: { _id: { "year": "$year", "month": "$month", ... }, average: { ... `

Comment: I want year to have month of that year only, and month to have days of that month only and so on.

2020" [
 {
 "04: [
  { "07": [
  { "21": {} }, { "19": {}}
]}
]
}
]. Not necessarily to have them as keys. It can be key value pairs.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add an example of what the output document looks like.

Comment: I added sample outout

Comment: I can do that with forEach and some variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the solution meets your requirements:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "channelId": "$channelId",
        "year": "$year",
        "month": "$month",
        "day": "$day",
        "hour": "$hour"
      },
      value: {
        $avg: "$value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "channelId": "$_id.channelId",
        "year": "$_id.year",
        "month": "$_id.month",
        "day": "$_id.day"
      },
      value: {
        $avg: "$value"
      },
      hours: {
        $push: {
          hour: "$_id.hour",
          value: "$value"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "channelId": "$_id.channelId",
        "year": "$_id.year",
        "month": "$_id.month"
      },
      value: {
        $avg: "$value"
      },
      days: {
        $push: {
          day: "$_id.day",
          value: "$value",
          hours: "$hours"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "channelId": "$_id.channelId",
        "year": "$_id.year"
      },
      value: {
        $avg: "$value"
      },
      months: {
        $push: {
          month: "$_id.month",
          value: "$value",
          days: "$days"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "channelId": "$_id.channelId"
      },
      channelId: {
        $first: "$_id.channelId"
      },
      value: {
        $avg: "$value"
      },
      aggregates: {
        $push: {
          year: "$_id.year",
          value: "$value",
          months: "$months"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vIhSX25JKDr)

Comment: Yes could you explain a little how the value is same infact you are taking average.

Comment: @GhazanfarKhan If you perform aggregation step by step, you can see how we are constructing the structure. AVG is calculated by grouping items. Normally, to build such structure with MongoDB aggregation, we need to start from bottom -> top.